# My captcha is checking if it is empty or wrong, but it is not checking if is right

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"><font color="#FF0000">*</font><strong>Captcha</strong>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?php echo '<img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha">'; ?>
            <br/>
            <span><input name="captcha_entered" type="text"  class="form-control" id="captcha_entered" size="27" maxlength="4"/></br></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="captcha_total" id="captcha_total" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rand_code']; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <center>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btn1\"/>");
            </script>
            <noscript>
                <p style="color: red;"><b><i>Please enable JavaScript to continue</i></b>
                    <p>
            </noscript>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript

```
function q_form_val() {
    var patt = new RegExp(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/);
    var captcha_entered = document.getElementById("captcha_entered").value;
    if (captcha_entered == "") {
        alert("Please enter the Captcha");
        return false;
    }else if(!patt.test(captcha_entered)){
        alert("Bad Captcha Match");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is also showing the same pop up message for a right captcha and for bad captcha.
Wrong and rigth captcha is showing the same error as a bad captcha.

What is the problem in right captcha?
What is the problem in validating?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I'd recommend looking into Google reCAPTCHA. A much nicer experience for your users, and really easy to implement.

Comment: where are you checking the value of captcha and the value entered by user?

Comment: where is the supposed captcha value?

Comment: @Dherya  i m checking in the form

Comment: <?php
session_start();
$code=rand(1000,9999);
$_SESSION["code"]=$code;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165); //background color blue
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color white
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

Comment: @ImmortalDude i am checking as 4412 but when i enter 4412 then it is showing "Bad captcha " popup

Comment: whats the regex for?

Comment: @Immortal Dude  var patt = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

Comment: actually you're not matching the value of captcha. The function that triggers the "bad captcha" is the time when you're testing the user's captcha value with a regex pattern

Comment: yeah but what it is for, your'e already matching the values the regex seems unnecessary

Comment: @Immortal Dude  var patt = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

Comment: @Dherya where to do changes?

Comment: @DiwakarYadav why are you posting your regex in response to my question

Comment: you supposed to check this 
$_SESSION["code"] == user_entered_captcha_value

Comment: i don't want to use regex ......

Comment: @Dherya Where should i place this code  $_SESSION["code"] == user_entered_captcha_value

Comment: @Dherya if i don't want to use regex and want to validate captcha then how should i can do?

Comment: wait a minute dude...

Answer (score 0):

Take help from this. It will solve your problem. Use it wisely

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['code'] = '1323'; // here will your captcha is stored  i have used a constant value;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
     <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick=" event.preventDefault(); q_form_val();">
        </form>
        <script>
            function q_form_val() {

                var captcha_entered = document.getElementById("captcha").value;
                if (captcha_entered == "") {
                    alert("Please enter the Captcha");
                    return false;
                }else if( captcha_entered == "<?php echo $_SESSION['code']; ?>" ){
                    alert("captcha matched");
                    return true;
                }else if( captcha_entered != "<?php echo $_SESSION['code']; ?>" ){
                    alert("captcha not matched");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Dhreya if the captcha does not match ....then what popup should show ?  where is the captcha not match popup

Comment: @Dhreya not working ..it is now redirecting me to thank-you.php page without submitted the form

Comment: try to console the value you get in captcha_entered variable

Comment: i have made it all for.. just make some changes and you are good to go... if you still want to discuss.. hit me